# Why the text id=box-2 was out of the box-2 ?Overlap rule on float in css

Tags: html, css

The css file is

```
#box {
    width:400px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid black;
}
#box-1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
#box-2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box">
  <div id="box-1">id=box-1</div>
  <div id="box-2">id=box-2</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

It is clear that box-2 was overlap by box-1.
Problems confused me:
1.box-1 was put in the box before box-2,why the result is not that box-2 overlap box-1?

[image]

2.Why the text `id=box-2` was not in box-2?
If box-2 was overlap by box-1 and the text `id=box-2` was in box-2,the result should be

[image]

Please tell me the principle of css float rule.

Comment: I think that my explanation is good, but if you don't understand something let me know please.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: It seems your answer is addressing the OP's last sentence, "Please tell me the principle of css float rule." itself a very broad request, while completely ignoring the rest of the question. I'm not sure why the OP put that sentence there considering they took the time to explain and illustrate their specific issue. It's like the OP is asking to get their question closed. (Don't get me wrong, I'm not knocking your answer, but the OP's question is confusing.)

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, but I make a good resume. Feel free to close this topic if you consideer. However I think that there's less explanations about this topic than the neededs, because the floats are not good explained in nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats are not for layouts, only to float elements. This is because the problems you are facing and most users don't understand.

The basic principle of CSS floats is that property gets out of the normal flow the floated element. At this point, when you float an element, the line-height where it is will be zero. I explain you with an example:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  clear:both;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.floated {
  float:left;
}
.box > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="floated">Floated div</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>Not Floated div</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example, the red border simulates the line height. You can see now that the content `.floated` is going out of the container `.box`, thanks of this the box appears without height and seems with no content. You can see also that `.box` are cleared to avoid the conflict you are facing.

Let's see another example. A common use of the floats are for grids. I don't agree with this method, but it's common to found this kind of procedures:

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.grid.floated .element {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.grid.inline-block {
  font-size: 0;
}
.grid.inline-block .element {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h1>Floated grid</h1>
<div class="grid floated">
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element with different height and content</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<h1>Inline block grid</h1>

<div class="grid inline-block">
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element with different height and content</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

What the hell? As you can see, the floated grid have a problem, the stack of the elements when one of the elements have more height than the others. This causes a lot of problems. The other thing is that we need to clear the floats just after it ends.

You can see the inline-block grid. None of the floated grid problems exist. You have the correct line height, the elements are in the normal flow of the document, the stack follows the correct order and you don't need to clear nothing.

### Another common float problems

If you start a layout with floats, you are required to float all following elements, at least if you don't clear everything everytime. Floated elements transforms into block elements. You can have got a `<span>` tag (inline element), and if you float it you'll obtain a block element (as a `<div>`) in the layer stack (the layer stack is compossed by floats, absolute positioning, opacities, etc). This causes a lot of problems if you don't understand fine how the floats works.

### Conclusions and recommendation

The conclusion is that floats are a good tool to make float elements (like an image to the left with the text following the flow at the right side), and floats were good when internet explorer don't accept inline-block or flexbox or another modern technique to layouts, but in the year 2016 there's no reason to make layouts with floats. My recommendation is to use another techniques (positions, displays, flexbox, inline-block elements, etc) and floats gets the use to float normal elements only.

Good luck!

Comment: Why the text  `id=box-2` was  out of the box-2 ? Which reason cause it out of the box-2 ？

Comment: AS you can see in the examples in this answer, the problem is the line height and that element goes out of the normal flow. That's the reason.